# How to prepend a nested class with a selector in SCSS?

Tags: sass

I have the following SCSS:

```
.parent-class {
  .class {
    background: lightgreen;

    img &-img{
      border: blue;
    }
  }  
}
```

...which produces this:

```
.parent-class .class {
  background: lightgreen;
}
img .parent-class .class-img {
  border: blue;
}
```

I'm trying to pre-pend the `.class-img` with the `img` selector and have my result be this `img.class-img`:

```
.parent-class .class {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.parent-class img.class-img {
  border: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd advocate for doing this but it is possible.

SCSS has an `@at-root` directive which allows you to output the content of the block at the root level. You can combine that with the `selector.unify()` function to build the selector you need.

The example given in the `@at-root` docs includes a `unify-parent` mixin which is particularly helpful in your case.

```
@use "sass:selector";

// Mixin optional - see below
@mixin unify-parent($child) {
  @at-root #{selector.unify(&, $child)} {
    @content;
  }
}

.parent-class {
  .class {
    background: lightgreen;
    
    // With the mixin
    @include unify-parent("img") {
      &-img {
        border:blue;
      }
    }

    // Without the mixin (be sure to keep @use though)
    @at-root #{selector.unify(&, img)}-img {
        border: blue;
    }
  }  
}
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root

Comment: In my effort to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I failed to mention that I have an outer parent class. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Millhorn I've revised my answer to address the additional complexity.

Comment: That is like a wall of SCSS. Wow!

Comment: @Millhorn Aye, drop the mixin if it's a one off and go with the second option to drastically reduce the amount of code you need. With that said, I'd definitely advise considering whether this is the approach you have to take. Personally, I'd do it the way Martin is suggesting.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Your answer was correct based on the question I asked, but I did go with Martin's approach. In a much larger site or something where the styles affect more than one element, I would have gone with yours.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Nathan is quite impressive and probably works as described (I didn't even know about `selector.unify()`). However I feel that it might be a case where I would go the Keep-it-simple route:

```
.parent-class {
  .class {
    background: lightgreen;
  }
  img.class-img {
    border: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't agree more :) I have to assume there's some reasoning I'm not aware of that prevents them from taking the simpler approach. I had fun writing that code but I can't ever imagine using it!